# OpenMeap - Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I'm new in OpenMeap and I need to manipulate mysql database instead SQlite3.
I followed these steps:

1. I configured setEnv.bat script

---

```
 @echo off
 rem  Ant
 set ANT_HOME=C:/Appache Software/apache-ant-1.9.4

 rem  OpenMEAP
 set ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:/Mobile_Team/android-sdk-windows
 set OPENMEAP_HOME=C:/OpenMEAP

 rem Required on services nodes.  Is used as an identity for a cluster node
 rem set OPENMEAP_CLUSTER_NODE_URL_PREFIX=http://localhost:8080/openmeap-     services-web

 rem Database settings.  Can also be passed as system properties.
 set OPENMEAP_JAVA_ENV=javase
 set OPENMEAP_JPA_SHOWSQL=false
 set OPENMEAP_JPA_GENERATEDDL=update
 set OPENMEAP_JPA_DIALECT=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
 set OPENMEAP_JDBC_DRIVERCLASS=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 set "OPENMEAP_JDBC_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openmeap?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true"
 set OPENMEAP_JDBC_URL=jdbc:mysql://172.16.0.81:3306/openmeap
 set OPENMEAP_JDBC_USERNAME=openmeap
 set OPENMEAP_JDBC_PASSWORD=openmeap

 rem  Path extending
 set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%OPENMEAP_HOME%/build-tools/scripts
```

2. Execute  ant dist-all-web and ant publish-local-slic-core
3. I build openmeap-admin-web on tomcatserver

I had this error : 
java.sql.SQLException: path to '/tmp/openmeap.db': 'C:\tmp' does not exist

Did I forget something ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to create a tmp folder on the drive you are using before spinning up the tomcat instance if your using sqlite.

If you would like to use mysql. Make the changes in the file below and rebuild your web project.

OpenMEAP/server-side/openmeap-shared-serverside/src/openmeap-jpa.properties

```
# either javase or javaee, javaee will use a container managed datasource, by default.
OPENMEAP_JAVA_ENV=javase
OPENMEAP_JPA_CONFIGURATION=openmeap-jpa-javase

OPENMEAP_HIBERNATE_CFG=hibernate.cfg.xml

OPENMEAP_JPA_SHOWSQL=false
OPENMEAP_JPA_GENERATEDDL=update
OPENMEAP_JPA_DIALECT=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#OPENMEAP_JPA_DIALECT=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLite3Dialect
OPENMEAP_JDBC_DRIVERCLASS=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#OPENMEAP_JDBC_DRIVERCLASS=org.sqlite.JDBC
OPENMEAP_JDBC_URL=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/openmeap
#OPENMEAP_JDBC_URL=jdbc:sqlite:/tmp/openmeap.db
OPENMEAP_JDBC_USERNAME=********
OPENMEAP_JDBC_PASSWORD=********
```

That worked for us. Seems like those variables are not overriding. A new tag for OpenMEAP should be created. The wiki and docs did not give us much for troubleshooting.